# Indexing specific rows in solr

Tags: solr

i m new to solr. 
I need to search in only specific set of rows in a table rather indexing whole database.
As far i have read, we have to index whole document for searching in solr.

Please tell if there is any way to index only specific set of rows from database in solr?

Comment: Indexing cannot be set on specific rows, it is always on columns.

Comment: you can use DIH feature of solr and retrieve specific rows from database (write your query for the same which will fetch specific records need to be indexed in the data-config.xml)

Comment: How are you indexing your content?

Comment: @MatsLindh i m indexing using data-config.xml file using the DIH defined in solrconfig.xml

Comment: Then the suggestion from @AbhijitBashetti seems like the way to go. Any reason why you can't just select the rows you need in your import query?

Comment: Build your query in the data-config.xml by adding the where clauses and get the required data from database to be indexed into the solr.

Comment: Hey, i think the indexing is based on columns. No matter what number of rows we restrict using where clause, solr will index whole database, however it will search within the rows that are specified in where clause in `data-config.xml`

Comment: @MatsLindh i think selecting specific set of rows in `data-config.xml` won't let that specific set of rows to be indexed(as solr index the whole database), however, indeed it limits the search to the set of rows that we specified in `data-config.xml`

Comment: @RohitRaghav Only the rows returned from the query will be indexed into Solr. Solr will not index the whole table, unless you return all rows from the table in your DIH / import query.